# How can I find the error for n=5033 in my Java program?

Tags: java

Given below is my code, how can I find the error on input 5033? The question is as follows:

> Sheldon, Leonard, Penny, Rajesh and Howard are in the queue for a
>   "Double Cola" drink vending machine; there are no other people in the
>   queue. The first one in the queue (Sheldon) buys a can, drinks it and
>   doubles! The resulting two Sheldons go to the end of the queue. Then
>   the next in the queue (Leonard) buys a can, drinks it and gets to the
>   end of the queue as two Leonards, and so on. This process continues ad
>   infinitum.
>
> For example, Penny drinks the third can of cola and the queue will
>   look like this: Rajesh, Howard, Sheldon, Sheldon, Leonard, Leonard,
>   Penny, Penny.
>
> Write a program that will print the name of a man who will drink the
>   n-th can.
>
> Note that in the very beginning the queue looks like that: Sheldon,
>   Leonard, Penny, Rajesh, Howard. The first person is Sheldon.
>
> Input The input data consist of a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 109).
>
> It is guaranteed that the pretests check the spelling of all the five
>   names, that is, that they contain all the five possible answers.
>
> Output Print the single line — the name of the person who drinks the
>   n-th can of cola. The cans are numbered starting from 1. Please note
>   that you should spell the names like this: "Sheldon", "Leonard",
>   "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard" (without the quotes). In that order
>   precisely the friends are in the queue initially.

```
import java.util.*;
public class sheldon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0, rem = 0, q = 0;
        if (n < 6) {
            if (n == 1)
                System.out.print("Sheldon");
            else if (n == 2)
                System.out.print("Leonard");
            else if (n == 3)
                System.out.print("Penny");
            else if (n == 4)
                System.out.print("Rajesh");
            else
                System.out.print("Howard");
        }
        else {
            n = n - 5;
            while (n != 0) {
                i++;
                rem = n;
                if ((10 * i) <= n) {
                    n = n - (10 * i);
                } else
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
            System.out.println(rem);

            q = (rem / (2 * i));
            if (q == 0)
                System.out.print("Sheldon");
            else if (q == 1)
                System.out.println("Leonard");
            else if (q == 2)
                System.out.print("Penny");
            else if (q == 3)
                System.out.print("Rajesh");
            else
                System.out.print("Howard");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "input 5033" mean? From the problem description you give, "The input data consist of a single integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 109)." So isn't 5033 an invalid input?

Comment: Also, what happens when you input 5033?

Comment: @GlorD: You need to [edit] your question to add more detail. What error are you actually getting? What goes wrong? What did you expect to happen instead? You might find [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a useful read in a situation like this.

Comment: First, you are printing `i` and `rem`, which shouldn’t be part of the output, that alone probably explains why your output isn’t accepted. Second your logic seems to be buggy. I believe Sheldon drinks the 6th and the 7th cola since there are two Sheldons in the queue after the first round. Then Leonard drinks the 8th and the 9th cola. Your output for 7, 8 and 9 is Leonard, Leonard and Penny. Off by 1?

Comment: Usually, questions accompanied with "plz help me" will be written off as lazy. We don't need please-halp pleading here anyway, since we like succinct questions, but really, do try to avoid txtspk `:-)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here we don't solve programming contest, but I can't stop my passion to solving this!

**Approach:**

The way of attacking this problem will be to write down some examples and look for a pattern.
Here’s the pattern for the first 5 drinks.
SH-L-P-R-H
After the 5th drink we have,
SH-SH-L-L-P-P-H-H
After the 10th drink we have,
SH-SH-SH-SH-L-L-L-L-P-P-P-P-H-H-H-H
After the 35th drink we have,
SH-SH-SH-SH-SH-SH-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-L-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-P-H-H-H-H-H-H-H-H

See the pattern?
Each single person in the doubles in the 2^ith block, where i=0,1,2…..and so on

So, when i=0, there are 2^0 number of each type of person in the block.
i=1, there are 2^1 number of each type of person in the block.
i=2, there are 2^2 number of each type of person in the block.

There are 5 types of person. So, in each block we have 2^i * 5 persons.

Now, our first problem is to find out to which block the nth can belongs. Why? See, if we could find out the i, then we could find out the starting position of the block, say p. Now, it’s just a matter of subtracting the starting position of the block from n and divide the result by 2^i (since we have those many people of each type) to get the drinker.

How do we find out to which position  ith drinker belongs?
We have to find out  the maximum i for which (2^i)*5 <= n

Observe that (2^i-1)*5 is the starting index of each block.

Now, (n – 2^i *5)/(2^i) gives the position of the drinker. Why? we know that in the ith block, first 2^i persons are Sheldon, next 2^i persons are Leonard and so on.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String[] names = {"Sheldon", "Leonard", "Penny", "Rajesh", "Howard"};
        int round = 1;
        while (n > 5 * round) {
            n = n - 5 * round;
            round *= 2;
        }
        System.out.println(names[(n + round - 1) / round - 1]);
    }

}
```